# fifo in sql query

Tags: sql, excel

Is there a possible way to find those negative number which does not knock of with the sum credits in future date.

[FIFO in sql](https://i.stack.im)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQNBZ.png)gur.com/pcwhp.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for Excel solution or SQL one cause it's hard to work with SQL without unique keys. I will try to give you suggestion how I would go for it assuming that every transaction has unique ID field.

First calculate all positive changes for account (this will be a part of solution but I split it for clarity).

```
SELECT 
    t.account, 
    SUM(t.debit) AS change_positive 
FROM 
    transactions AS t 
WHERE 
    t.debit > 0 
GROUP BY 
    t.account
```

Now you will have total value of recovered debit by account. In this case **35** (10 + 5 +20)

Now you have to do similar operation for debits (negative change) but only till current operation eg. for 12/21/2017 it's -20, for 12/25/2017 it's -55. When you have value of debits_till_date you will know if payments_total has covered that payment or if it was already too much debt to be covered by payments. In SQL as a total query (including previous one) it would look like this:

```
SELECT
    q.account,
    q.date,
    q.transaction_debit,
    q.remainings_from_payments
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.account,
            t.date,
            t.debit AS transaction_debit,
            SUM(t2.debit) AS debits_till_date,
            i.payments_total,
            SUM(t2.debit) + i.payments_total AS remainings_from_payments
        FROM
            transactions AS t
        LEFT JOIN transactions AS t2 ON t.account = t2.account AND t.date >= t2.date AND t2.debit < 0
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.account, SUM(t.debit) AS payments_total FROM transactions AS t WHERE t.debit > 0 GROUP BY t.account) AS i ON t.account =     i.account
        GROUP BY
            t.account, t.date
    ) AS q
    WHERE
        q.transaction_debit < 0
        AND q.remainings_from_payments < 0
```

If you remove last part "AND q.remainings_from_payments < 0" you will be able to see how much of payments remained after every negative transaction.

---

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1c734/2)

Comment: Hi StromoPL, thanks for the query. let me try if it works.actually i looking at same solution as in the link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/FIFO+Queues/145613/      i have only SQL DB2 and not sure how to use the query mentined in the link. as well i dont have a unique id for transaction. only identifier is the sum of credits and debit for the date.

Comment: Chris, I updated query to use "date" field and avoid "id". It should work as long as dates within accounts are unique. Query I provided was tested on mySQL but it is quite standard and should work on any db supporting plain SQL (just rename "transactions" table from query to whatever is the name of your table)

Comment: You are using duplicated dates for the transactions per account. It makes grouping unreliable. You need either introduce "id" column that every transaction would be unique or have every date for account used only once. Otherwise even if you get result pointing that transaction from 2017-12-24 is not recovered you will not know which transaction it is because there are 2 with such date.

Comment: hi Stromo, first of all thank you so much. i do find my self closer to teh result what i need , i small query , when i introduce one more insert for date 26-12-2017 and amount as -20 , i do get 2 rows for a1 , 24th =-20 and 26th=-40 . is it possible to show 26th date as -20

Comment: If you mean the original transaction debit value than sure - just use "q.transaction_debit" field in fields list. I updated query and SQLFiddle demo to return 2 transactions (from 24th and 26th) and to return original transaction value.

Comment: hi Stomo, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d62e/1  please check for me on this SQL , looks like my outstanding should be  -13732818 , how do i understand the 3 records. need your help here. thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer to sample excel for results and understanding.

Comment: i see it is getting Cumulated with th leftover balance , instead can i have the actual outstanding for those dates

Comment: @ChristopherLewis: These 3 records which you get are negative transactions which are not covered by total amount of positive (recovered ones). So all the recovered monay were enough to cover all debts except 3 last ones (in Excel you have them marked in green). Field `remainings_from_payments` informs you how much of recovered money left after you have paid negative transaction till that date (including the transaction for wich it is displayed). So if you want you final current balance than you need to look at last transaction which is from 2011-06-30 and is exactly (-13732818)

Comment: @ChristopherLewis: Value of `remainings_from_payments` is actual outstanding balance for these dates. Negative values are cumulated till that date but they are also compared to total recovered amounts (past & future) which shows you how much is to be recovered at that date. You have to be aware though that current debt for dates in this case is a bit tricky concept as you use amounts of all recovered money and not money recovered till date. So balance for dates will be different and will be changing depending on all recovered money after that date. But I assume that this is how it should work.